# Listen Android incoming SMS when Google Hangout or other app receives it

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use a broadcast receiver to read incoming SMS in my app and also able to do so. However, if someone receives SMS on google hangout instead of default SMS app, the broadcast receiver doesn't work.

The following is the code I am using:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

The manifest has:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: Yes added that permission as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the android priority value to a suitable value.

> Ordered broadcasts (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the android:priority attribute of the matching intent-filter; receivers with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.

Comment: What sort of permission will I need to add for that?

Comment: Not a permission but you need to add an `android:priority` = statement in the android manifest file.