# SMS Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms, listener

Alright, I have tried every solution on Stack and nothing works.My current method registers the "SmsListener" receiver from the MainActivity. All I'm trying to do is initialize the onReceive method. There are no errors; It simply isn't picking up a broadcast. What am I doing wrong? Pasting the applicable code here. Anything else that may be needed please just ask.

*Update:
Here is a similar unresolved issue
[Listen Android incoming SMS when Google Hangout or other app receives it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022569/listen-android-incoming-sms-when-google-hangout-or-other-app-receives-it)
I am testing under Android 6.0.1. Target Sdk version is 22. Min Sdk is 19. It's worth noting that I just tested my original code on an LG Optimus GPro with Android 4.4.2 and it worked. It still isn't working on my Nexus with Android 6.0.1.*

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.biapps.makin_biscuits">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action `android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />`
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ContactsList">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsListener"
        android:priority="999"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

    </receiver>


</application>
```

Main Activity

```
    package com.biapps.makin_biscuits;

    import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;

    import android.content.Context;

    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.content.Intent;

    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //set object labels and states here
    private ImageButton icon;
    private AudioManager am;
    private ImageButton people;
    private ImageButton ring;
    private NotificationManager nm;
    private NotificationListenerService nls;
    IncomingCallReceiver broadCastReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    SmsListener smsReceiver = new SmsListener();
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        icon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
        people = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.people);
        //people.setOnClickListener(peopleButtonHandler);
        ring = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ring);

    }

    int buttonstate = 0;
    public View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (buttonstate == 0) {

                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonup);
                buttonstate = 1;
                am.setRingerMode(0);

                registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
                registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        "android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"));
                registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
                registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        "android.provider.Telephony.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Diving!", `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)`
                        .show();

            } else {

                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.button);
                buttonstate = 0;
                am.setRingerMode(2);

                unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver);
                unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Surfacing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    };}
```

SmsListener

```
package com.biapps.makin_biscuits;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;


public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "SmsListener";

public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "ON SMS RECEIVE BROADCAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i(TAG, "SmsListener - onReceiveCalled");

}}
```

Comment: Is your `MainActivity` running in the foreground when the SMS is received? What's your `targetSdkVersion`, and which version of Android are you testing under?

Comment: I am testing under 6.0.1. Target Sdk version is 22. Min Sdk is 19. Yes MainActivity is in the foreground. It's worth noting that I just tested my original code on an LG Optimus GPro with Android 4.4.2 and it worked. It still isn't working on my Nexus with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Similar unresolved issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022569/listen-android-incoming-sms-when-google-hangout-or-other-app-receives-it

Comment: Most likely not. If Hangouts is causing the problem there, it's because it's intercepting and aborting the broadcast before that user's Receiver gets it. Your Nexus is running Marshmallow. The `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast cannot be aborted in that version.

Comment: Interesting. Do you think it could have something to do with using Google Fi phone service?

Comment: Dunno. It's possible, if Hangouts uses some other protocol for text messaging while on Google Fi, but I'm not at all familiar with Fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

First make another app your default SMS app.

Then: Google Hangout --> Settings (Disable merged conversations) --> SMS (Disable SMS)

Answer (score 8):

Try following way with highest reading priority value,

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsListener"
             android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.READ_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This will surely solve out your problem.

Update from below comment,

Since you are checking on Android version 6.0.1 just follow these steps,

1. Go to Settings,
2. Go to Apps
3. Select your Application
4. Choose Permissions Option
5. Enable SMS permission

Comment: I tried this. It still doesn't work. It's worth noting that I just tested my original code on an LG Optimus GPro with Android 4.4.2 and it worked. It still isn't working on my Nexus with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: I have a feeling another app is taking priority and blocking broadcasts, but I've uninstalled both Google Hangouts and Facebook messenger and still can't get it to run. I also queried Receivers and only returned 05-04 01:20:13.141 31026-31026/com.biapps.Diive I/System.out: Receiver name:com.google.android.gms.icing.proxy.SmsMonitor; priority=0.

Comment: Try unlistall & re-install your application in Nexus. It must work.

Comment: Do you use Google Hangouts on your nexus 5 that is working? It appears that in my Nexus all messages get filtered to Hangouts whether I choose it or not. Could this be causing the issue? @Arjun

Comment: @Jake, Yes I do use Hangout. No that can not be an issue.

Comment: It can't? How do you know?

Comment: well because I too developed same SMS reader code and it is working find in my Nexus Phone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021492/enabling-sms-support-in-hangouts-2-0-breaks-the-broadcastreceiver-of-sms-receive

Comment: Well I do have hungout in my Nexus 5 , but code for SMS reading is working fine.

Comment: enabling the sms permission did it for me. I didn't know I had to go to apps to do it.

Comment: applying this setting worked for me but if we already have granted the permission why the hell is this needed?

Answer (score 6):

After spending more than an hour I found that `RECEIVE_SMS` permission is required.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, 
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE);
```

Prioirty is not required to be set. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering `broadcast` your in your `Activity`, so it won't work if your app is in background. you can remove this from your `Activity` and you can register it in Manifest.

ex:

```
 <receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Along with this add permission to recieve sms.

Try this, and it will work

Comment: I tried this. It still doesn't work. It's worth noting that I just tested my original code on an LG Optimus GPro with Android 4.4.2 and it worked. It still isn't working on my Nexus with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: how you are testing this ?

Comment: I've been using Run 'app' in android studio with my Nexus connected. I also generated a signed APK and sent it to myself to assure that that wasn't the issue.

Comment: I mean how you are receiving sms ? Sending sms from other device or you are using adb command or you are using any fake sms tool ?

Comment: Also go through http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I am sending messages from another device!

Comment: I went through that documentation and didn't come to a solution.

Comment: Similar unresolved issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022569/listen-android-incoming-sms-when-google-hangout-or-other-app-receives-it